# Non Default IIS WebSite Loads Default Website

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

I have IIS setup on Server 2012R2 with 3 websites.  Websites are Default, Site1 and Site2.  Default and Site1 are live sites hosting content.  Site2 is a new site which is live and hosting no content.  DNS entry created as Alias (CNAME).  Alias name is website2, FQDN is website2.domain.com and FQDN for target host is www.domain.com. Host name for website site2 in IIS is website2.domain.com.  When I load the site on the server I get a server error.  When I load the site on my pc I get the Default Site.  Why is the Default Site loading? Does the Default Site load because there is no content in Site2?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps try just `domain.com` (rather than `www.domain.com`) for the CNAME target domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

Site2 loaded after added content to it.